# MVC + Nhibernate + Oracle Schema Configuration

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, oracle10g

Our customer wants us to use a connectionstring with username = "external" and add schemaName "original" infront of our queries like:

"select columnA from original.TableA"

- I dont want to change mapping files which are shared by other projects,
- tried adding default schema as:

  `<property name="default_schema">original</property>`

But this doesn't work. Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i added a key to the application settings and include default schema to the fluent nhibernate configuration.

```
Fluently.Configure().
Database(OracleClientConfiguration.
Oracle10.Dialect<Oracle10gDialect>().
Driver<OracleDriver>().
DefaultSchema(defaultSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the defaultSchema as outlined in the answer below does not work for us. We have to call 'alter session set schema=' on our session. Otherwise we get the error "table or view not found'.